# display dynamic dropdown values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am making a form to insert data about article. I have a table named "articles" and an other "categories". At table articles is a row named categories_id which contains id of a specific category. At my form I have a field named "categories" which is dropdown. I am using DataList. What I want is to display all categories from table "categories" in that dropdown and when user select one of them, in table "articles" to save the corresponding id category. In php i do this whith an associative array, but here I don't really know how to do it because I am new at this language.

```
  <fieldset>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpdKategoria" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
  </fieldset>               
 <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Shto" />


  public partial class AddArticle : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connection = n                 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
            try
            {

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {

                    Bind();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());

            }
        }

        public void Bind()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from artikulli", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            datalist2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            datalist2.DataBind();
        }

        protected void datalist2_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
            {
                TextBox txtTema = e.Item.FindControl("txtTema") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtAbstrakti = e.Item.FindControl("txtAbstrakti") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtKeywords = e.Item.FindControl("txtKeywords") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtKategoria = e.Item.FindControl("txtKategoria") as TextBox;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = "Insert into artikulli(tema,abstrakti,path,keywords,kategoria_id) values (@tema,@abstrakti,@filename,@keywords,@kategoria)";
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tema", txtTema.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@abstrakti", txtAbstrakti.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@keywords", txtKeywords.Text));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@kategoria", txtKategoria.Text));

                FileUpload FileUploadArtikull = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("FileUploadArtikull");

                if (FileUploadArtikull.HasFile)
                {
                    int filesize = FileUploadArtikull.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    if (filesize > 4194304)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Maximumi i madhesise se file qe lejohet eshte 4MB');", true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string filename = "artikuj/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadArtikull.PostedFile.FileName);
                        //add parameters
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", filename);

                        conn.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                        Bind();

                        FileUploadArtikull.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/artikuj\\" + FileUploadArtikull.FileName));
                        Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('ERROR');", true);
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

My table artikulli has this fields:

```
id                       int    Unchecked
tema                 varchar(250)   Checked
abstrakti                text   Checked
data_publikimit      date   Checked
path                 varchar(350)   Checked
keywords                 varchar(350)   Checked
kategoria_id         int    Checked
departamenti_id      int    Checked
```

Table kategoria has this fields:

```
id          int Unchecked
emertimi    varchar(350)    Checked
```

I want to get names of categories from field "emertimi" and display at dropdown, but for each name to have index of id, and when selected one of them, to save id in field "kategoria_id"

Comment: you don't want to bind to the datalist insert event instead you want to bind to the dropdown select event

Comment: Ok but i want to know how display values and save selected "value" -> "id" at table "catgores"

Comment: @user3592644 - The point of my comment was to explain your confusion with the new platform not write the code for you.  Typically a question that asks for all the code to be written is un-acceptable on this site.  You can read the faq for more information.  Given a reasonable understanding of ASP.NET and my comment you could have coded this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a sample program, and please take care of SQL Injection yourself.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdKategoria" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" 
            onclick="btnInsert_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and .cs page cod is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\\My Projects\\practice\\asp.net\\drpdTest\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bindCategory();
        }
    }

    private void ConnectionStatus()  // Checking connection Status either it is open or not
    {
        if (ConnectionState.Closed == con.State)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Response.Write("<script language= 'JavaScript'> alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
            }
        }
    }

    private void bindCategory()  // binding data to DropDownList
    {
        ConnectionStatus();
        string Qry = "select * from category";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Qry, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        drpdKategoria.DataSource = ds;
        drpdKategoria.DataValueField = "category_id";  // Value of bided list in your dropdown in your case it will be CATEGORY_ID
        drpdKategoria.DataTextField = "category_name"; // this will show Category name in your dropdown
        drpdKategoria.DataBind();
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        ds.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
    }
    private void insertData()
    {
        ConnectionStatus();  // Checking connection state either it is open or not.
        string Qry = "insert into article (categories_id) values('"+drpdKategoria.SelectedValue+"')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, con);
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Response.Write("<script language= 'JavaScript'> alert('Record Inserted Please Check Your table')</script>");
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language= 'JavaScript'> alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
        }

    }
    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        insertData();
    }
}
```

Comment: this should be method Bind()??

Comment: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList' does not contain a definition for 'DataTextField' and no extension method 'DataTextField'

Comment: and i don't want to display id's of categories at dropdown, but instead to display name of categories from table "categories" and when selected one to save id of that specific category in "articles" "categories_id" field

Comment: I have edited my code which should be at your .aspx page, please check

Comment: </asp:TextBox> this should be </asp:DropDownList>. And still the same problem with DataTextField

Comment: Ok.. let me install Visual Studio I'll solve your problem... just wait for a while

Comment: mean while send me script of **artikulli** table I'll put dummy records in it and then send you complete code...

Comment: so, you want a drop down list containing Categories (fetching from categories table) and when user select and click on save button then it should insert category's id in your **Article** table, is it so?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51966/discussion-between-ravi-and-user3592644)